# My custom cape's devicetree fails to load at boot, but can be loaded manually

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, device-tree

If I load my own device-tree overlay from a shell it loads fine, but if I try to load it at boot, it won't do so. What am I missing?

It is a debian BeagleBone Black that I set up using bone-debian-7.4-2014-04-23-2gb.img.xz
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 01:36:09 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux

Here is the change that I made to /boot/uboot/uEnv.txt :

> **optargs=capemgr.enable_partno=BB-FOO-GPIO**

This is the output of **dmesg | grep bone-capemgr** :

> Baseboard: 'A335BNLT,00A5,4049BBBK7400'
>   compatible-baseboard=ti,beaglebone-black
>   slot #0: No cape found
>   slot #1: No cape found
>   slot #2: No cape found
>   slot #3: No cape found
>   slot #4: specific override
>   bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 4
>   slot #4: 'Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G'
>   slot #5: specific override
>   bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 5
>   slot #5: 'Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI'
>   slot #6: specific override
>   bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 6
>   slot #6: 'Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN'
>   **enabled_partno part_number 'BB-FOO-GPIO', version 'N/A', prio '0'**
>   slot #7: generic override
>   bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 7
>   slot #7: 'Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-FOO-GPIO'
>   loader: before slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: before slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: before slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   loader: check slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   initialized OK.
>   loader: check slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   **loader: before slot-7 BB-FOO-GPIO:00A0 (prio 0)**
>   **loader: check slot-7 BB-FOO-GPIO:00A0 (prio 0)**
>   **loader: after slot-7 BB-FOO-GPIO:00A0 (prio 0)**
>   **slot #7: Requesting part number/version based 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo**
>   **slot #7: Requesting firmware 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo' for board-name 'Override Board Name', version '00A0'**
>   **failed to load firmware 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo'**
>   **loader: failed to load slot-7 BB-FOO-GPIO:00A0 (prio 0)**
>   loader: check slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   loader: check slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: after slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   slot #5: Requesting firmware 'cape-boneblack-hdmi-00A0.dtbo' for board-name 'Bone-Black-HDMI', version '00A0'
>   slot #5: dtbo 'cape-boneblack-hdmi-00A0.dtbo' loaded; converting to live tree
>   slot #5: #4 overlays
>   loader: check slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: after slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   slot #4: Requesting firmware 'cape-bone-2g-emmc1.dtbo' for board-name 'Bone-LT-eMMC-2G', version '00A0'
>   slot #4: dtbo 'cape-bone-2g-emmc1.dtbo' loaded; converting to live tree
>   slot #4: #2 overlays
>   slot #4: Applied #2 overlays.
>   loader: done slot-4 BB-BONE-EMMC-2G:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   slot #5: Applied #4 overlays.
>   loader: done slot-5 BB-BONELT-HDMI:00A0 (prio 1)
>   loader: check slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   loader: after slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
>   slot #6: Requesting firmware 'cape-boneblack-hdmin-00A0.dtbo' for board-name 'Bone-Black-HDMIN', version '00A0'
>   slot #6: dtbo 'cape-boneblack-hdmin-00A0.dtbo' loaded; converting to live tree
>   slot #6: BB-BONELT-HDMIN conflict P8.45 (#5:BB-BONELT-HDMI)
>   slot #6: Failed verification
>   loader: failed to load slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)

Here is my source file for the device-tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    /* Identification */
    part-number = "BB-FOO-GPIO";
    version = "00A0";

    /* Resources required */
    exclusive-use =
        "P9.27",        /* XXX */
        "P9.23",        /* XXX */
        "gpio3_19",     /* XXX */
        "gpio1_17";     /* XXX */

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            foo_gpio_pins: pinmux_gpio_helper_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x1a4 0x0f      /* P9.27 GPIO3_19: MODE7 - OUTPUT */
                    0x044 0x2f      /* P9.23 GPIO1_17: MODE7 - INPUT */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;    /* On-chip Peripherals */
        __overlay__ {

            foo_gpio_helper {
                compatible = "gpio-of-helper";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&foo_gpio_pins>;
                status = "okay";

                foo_test_output {
                    gpio-name = "foo_test_output";
                    gpio = <&gpio4 19 0x00>;            /* gpio4 => GPIO-3 */
                    output;
                    init-high;
                };

                foo_test_input {
                    gpio-name = "foo_test_input";
                    gpio = <&gpio2 17 0x00>;            /* gpio2 => GPIO-1 */
                    input;
                    count-rising-edge;
                    count-falling-edge;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

~
(I compiled it so: **dtc -O dtb -o BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo -b 0 -@ BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dts**}

Now loading it manually using **echo BB-FOO-GPIO > $SLOTS"** it loads fine..
**dmesg -c** gives me:

> bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: part_number 'BB-FOO-GPIO', version 'N/A'
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: generic override
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 8
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: 'Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-FOO-GPIO'
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: Requesting part number/version based 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: Requesting firmware 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo' for board-name 'Override Board Name', version '00A0'
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: dtbo 'BB-FOO-GPIO-00A0.dtbo' loaded; converting to live tree
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: #2 overlays
>   of_get_named_gpio_flags exited with status 17
>   gpio-of-helper foo_gpio_helper.15: Allocated GPIO id=0
>   of_get_named_gpio_flags exited with status 115
>   gpio-of-helper foo_gpio_helper.15: Allocated GPIO id=1
>   gpio-of-helper foo_gpio_helper.15: ready
>   bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #8: Applied #2 overlays.

And **cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots** gives me what I desire:

0: 54:PF---
 1: 55:PF---
 2: 56:PF---
 3: 57:PF---
 4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
 5: ff:P-O-L Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
 8: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-FOO-GPIO

So, what am I missing? Why won't it load at boot time, but it will from a shell? The problem seems related to firmware not being loaded... I don't understand.

Comment: *"The problem seems related to firmware not being loaded"* -- FW is loaded by a userspace process, so a driver cannot get its firmware until Busybox is executing. A driver that need FW usually is built as a loadable module (i.e. read from the mounted rootfs) or specified as **late_initcall()** in order to defer execution of its initialization routine.

Comment: Is there a way for me to tell it that there is no firmware? (I assume that by "firmware" it is referring to some flash chip on a cape that it would normally read?)

Comment: Firmware for devices are stored in **/lib/firmware** of the rootfs.  If the driver is notified that the firmware does not exist, then the typical driver fails to initialize.  See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/firmware_class/README

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue that has a solution described in the link: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Loading_custom_capes

I hope it helps,
George

Comment: I guess this should be a comment, unless you give more details and you are sure about the answer responds the question.

Comment: The solution in that link (adding the cape name to /etc/default/capemgr) worked for me (using 3.8.13 kernel).

Answer (score 2):

The problem ist caused by the fact that the root filesystem (in my case on the eMMC) is not yet mounted when the kernel tries to load the overlay. I solved the problem by manually modifying the initramfs:

- Follow the instructions on e.g. http://backreference.org/2010/07/04/modifying-initrdinitramfs-files/ to unpack the file /boot/uboot/initrd.img
- Add the folder /lib/firmware to the unpacked archive and copy your *.dtbo file into this folder
- Pack and compress the initrd again and copy it back to /boot/uboot (while keeping a copy of the original file).

On the next reboot, the dtbo should be loaded:

```
 0: 54:P---L BEAGLE-GO-CAPE,00A0,FH-Aachen/FZJ,cape-beaglego
 1: 55:PF--- 
 2: 56:PF--- 
 3: 57:PF--- 
 4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
 5: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
 6: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

Comment: THIS should be the answer! Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem eliminating the "-b 0" clause in the dtc command.
I didn't spend many time to deeper investigate, but -b means "set the physical boot CPU" (as from manual page) and, may be, it conflicts during start-up.

Answer (score 1):

George provided a link with details of a workaround. This is the actual workaround:

```
add "CAPE=BB-FOO-GPIO" to /etc/default/capemgr
```

.. and remove the code from /boot/uboot/uEnv.txt

Answer (score 0):

There are a few conflating ideas here that I just worked through and wanted to update this answer so that the next person doesn't have to spend as much time as I did.

First, it seems that the latest versions of Ubuntu or Debian on Beaglebone Black (as of today) do not honor the uEnv.txt flags for the reasons described in [loading custom capes](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Loading_custom_capes) because of a chicken and egg problem with booting from a filesystem that isn't loaded yet. So, per ther link, the directions say to add `CAPE=<CAPE NAME HERE>` to `/etc/default/capemgr`.

Second, you need to make sure you're running an operating system that respects this new file, e.g., @RobertCNelson's Ubuntu build that provides init scripts that respect `/etc/default/capemgr`. See an [example](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/omap-image-builder/blob/master/target/init_scripts/capemgr-debian.sh).

So, in a nutshell, you need to make sure you're running one of the custom OS that respect `/etc/default/capemgr` before blindly making those changes, as I did.